# Unable to Update score in Quiz App

Tags: android

i am making a quiz aplication using sqlite. but i am unable to increment score in my project.

My DbHelper class is:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    dbase=db;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
    + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
    +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    addQuestions();
    //db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestions()
    {
    Question q1=new Question("Which company is the largest manufacturer" +
    " of network equipment?","HP", "IBM", "CISCO", "C");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("Which of the following is NOT " +
    "an operating system?", "SuSe", "BIOS", "DOS", "B");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("Which of the following is the fastest" +
    " writable memory?","RAM", "FLASH","Register","C");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("Which of the following device" +
    " regulates internet traffic?",    "Router", "Bridge", "Hub","A");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("Which of the following is NOT an" +
    " interpreted language?","Ruby","Python","BASIC","C");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
    Question quest = new Question();
    quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
    quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
    quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
    quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
    quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
    quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
    quesList.add(quest);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // return quest list
    return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
    int row=0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    row=cursor.getCount();
    return row;
    }
    }
```

My Activity class is:

```
public class OkokActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
setQuestionView();
butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
{
score++;
Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
}
if(qid<5){
currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
setQuestionView();
}else{
Intent intent = new Intent(OkokActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
startActivity(intent);
finish();
}
}
});
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_quiz, menu);
return true;
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
qid++;
}
}
```

i have passed the score using a bundle, to result activity. bit it always shows 0.
please help me find my fault.

Comment: Does `Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);` print your score on log

Comment: yup that is for checking in eclipse.

Comment: have u tried debugging to check if your score is increasing as per the answers...

Comment: but actually i have displayed the score in a textview in my result activity. but the problem is that it shows 0 always.

Comment: then update your textView on score updated

Comment: do `scoreTextView.setText(score);` after `score++;`

Comment: i have don that by using tv.setText()

Comment: i have done that in my result activity after passing score thorugh a bundle

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html for debugging

Comment: i am unable to understand the Debug mode. plz just see if there is any problem in my code due to which score isn't incrementing.